# Extract Sub string between two string pattern using Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am new to regular expression. I need to extract between two string pattern (**[[tag::** & **]]**) and for each occurrence.

For Example:

If the text is :

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus [[tag::4797897]] mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.
[[tag::4797800]] [[tag::4797769]]
```

As I want the extract text between **[[tag::** and **]]** ,  the expected output should be 4797897 ,  4797800 and 4797769

I am using Javascript and JQuery

Can some please help me . Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired results you can use the [`exec()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_exec.asp) method in a loop, pushing the match result of the [capturing](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) group to the results array.

```
var str = ' ... '
var re  = /\[\[tag::([^\]]+)]]/g, 
matches = [];

while (m = re.exec(str)) {
  matches.push(m[1]);
}

console.log(matches) //=> [ '4797897', '4797800', '4797769' ]
```

Comment: You're welcome. Next time when a question like this is asked please consider posting what you have attempted to try and solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html).

```
\[\[tag::(.*?)]]
```

Get the value you want from group index 1. `.*?` will do a non-greedy match of zero or more characters. `[` is a regex meta character which denotes the start of a character class. So you need to escape `[` in your regex in-order to  match a literal `[` symbol.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bT2mE4/1)

```
> var str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus [[tag::4797897]] mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.\nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus [[tag::4797897]] mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu.\n[[tag::4797800]] [[tag::4797769]]"
> var re = /\[\[tag::(.*?)]]/g;
> while (m = re.exec(str)) {
... match.push(m[1]);
... }
> console.log(match)
[ '4797897', '4797800', '4797769' ]
```